# Operation meaning in set theory

Tags: notation

When reading a set theorem, there is a part that:

- Defined a sequence $S_{n}$.
- Let $N = \inf\{n:S_{n}=0\}$ and let $X_{n} = S_{N \land n}$

I could not understand the operation $ \land$ in $S_{N \land n}$. Is this "and" operation? If it's true so what is it meaning of $S_{N \land n}$?

I hope someone can explain it to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I suspect $N\wedge n=\min(n,N)$. In orders $p\wedge q$ is used to denote the largest lower bound of $\{p,q\}$.

Comment: @drhab: Thank you for your suggestion. Since the value of $N$ is scalar. If $N \land  n = \min(n,N)$, the value of $X_{n}$ will equal to the value of $S_{n}$ while  $n = 1 : N-1$. After that all the values of $X_{n}$ will be the same as $S_{N}$. Is that right?

Comment: If $n<N$ then $X_n=S_{n\wedge N}=S_n\neq 0$. If $n\geq N$ then $X_n=S_{n\wedge N}=S_N=0$.

Comment: If you continue reading to the point where the author draws conclusions about the behavior of $X_n$, it might become clear what it's expected to mean. For that matter, it would help if you could quote or photograph the context in your question.